# how to set msbuild script path in ccnet.config using cruise control.net

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I am getting below execption when i am trying to run script using cruise control.please look into my code and let me know where i am doing mistake

```
<build date="2013-07-02 16:38:56" buildtime="00:00:00" error="true" buildcondition="ForceBuild">MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: e:\mybuild.xml
```

ccnet.config file

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <project name="Visteon">
    <webURL>http://localhost:333/ccnet/</webURL>

    <triggers>
      <intervalTrigger seconds="110" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
    </triggers>

    <tasks>

     <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>

        <workingDirectory>E:\workingproject_5145</workingDirectory>

    <projectFile>myproject.sln</projectFile>

    <buildArgs>msbuild e:\mybuild.xml /t:Buildrun</buildArgs> 


    <timeout>120</timeout>

    <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>

      </msbuild>




    </tasks>
  </project>

</cruisecontrol>
```

**my scriptsis defined in mybuild.xml which is below mentioned**

```
<Target Name="GetSource">
    <Message Text="Checking out trunk into $(SourceDirectory)" />
    <SvnCheckout RepositoryPath="$(SvnCheckoutPath)"
        LocalPath="$(CheckOutPath)"
        UserName="aa"
        Password="aa">
      <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
    </SvnCheckout>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Buildrun" DependsOnTargets="GetSource;Clean;" />
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <!-- Clean, then rebuild entire solution -->
    <MSBuild Projects="$(CheckOutPath)\myproject.sln" Targets="Clean;Rebuild" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: If you found an answer to your issue, please mark one of the responses as "the answer".  If you answered yourself (without any help from here).....then etiquette is to post your own answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Your projectFile should be the xml file...(that is a .msbuild file)

I think this is what you want.

```
 <projectFile>mybuild.xml</projectFile>

    <buildArgs>/t:Buildrun</buildArgs>
```

LONG VERSION:

```
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>

    <workingDirectory>E:\workingproject_5145</workingDirectory>

    <projectFile>myproject.sln</projectFile>

    <buildArgs>msbuild e:\mybuild.xml /t:Buildrun</buildArgs>
```

So it's gonna concatenate these values

$executable $workingDirectory $projectFile $buildArgs

So you get something like this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe E:\workingproject_5145\myproject.sln msbuild e:\mybuild.xml /t:Buildrun
```

which is not what you want.

If you make the values like this:

```
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>

    <workingDirectory>E:\workingproject_5145</workingDirectory>

    <projectFile>mybuild.xml</projectFile>

    <buildArgs>/t:Buildrun</buildArgs>
```

You'll get something like this:

```
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "E:\workingproject_5145\mybuild.xml" /t:Buildrun
```

Comment: If any answer helps or resolves your issue, you should mark it as "The Answer" so your question does not keep coming up as "unanswered".